# How can I measure lengths greater than 50' to a precision of less than 1/16"?

Tags: tools, measuring

Is it possible to measure a length greater than 50' to a precision less than 1/16"?

If so, what tools and/or techniques should I use to do so?

Comment: This is s 'shopping' question, which are typically not a great fit for this site.  Check out http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I was thinking "Which tools, materials, and best practices for home improvement task"

Comment: Did you mean 50 FT  50 '?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "shop for me" type question.  

Comment: I disagree that this is a shopping question. In fact, it's a very interesting question if reworded slightly: *can* a tape mearsure over 50ft long be accurate to 1/16th of an inch? (My guess is that due to stretching, heat expansion/contraction, etc, no)

Comment: A question of the form "does X exist?" is a shopping question; asking "**how** do I do Y?" is OK, even if the answer is "Buy X".  Yes, we're weird. :) Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The laser measuring devices are in that range.  A 100' metal tape has temperature coefficient expansion issues.

There are surveyors metal (and fiberglass) tapes on reels.

[image]